# How to debug my program that runs properly but returns segmentation fault in an ide?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>

class biker
{

public:
    int initspeed, acc, speeding;

};

void input(int n, biker a[])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //cout<<"Enter the initspeed:"<<"\n";
        std::cin >> a[i].initspeed;
        //cout<<"Enter the acceleration:"<<"\n";
        std::cin >> a[i].acc;
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n = 0, i = 0, t = 0, max_speed = 0, flag = 0, minimum = 0;
    biker a[100];

    std::cin >> t;

    for (int k = 0; k < t; k++)
    {
//cout<<"Enter no of bikers"<<"\n";
        std::cin >> n;
//cout<<"enter the max track speed"<<"\n";
        std::cin >> max_speed;
//cout<<"Enter the min niker speed"<<"\n";
        std::cin >> minimum;

        input(n, a);

        int j = 1, x = 0;
        while (flag < 500)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int prod = 0;
                prod = a[i].acc * j;
                x = a[i].initspeed + prod;
                // cout<<"VAL"<<x<<"\n";
                if (x >= minimum)
                {
//cout<<"It is greater than minimum";

                    sum = sum + a[i].initspeed + prod;
                    //cout<<sum<<"\n";

                }

            }
            if (sum >= max_speed)
            {
                //cout<<"MAXIMUM ACHIEVED\n";
                x = sum;
                break;
            }
            j++;
            flag++;
        }

//cout<<x<<"\n";
        std::cout << j;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is my solution to the [bike racing problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/bike-racing/0) in geeksforgeeks.

Summary:

A Bike race is to be organized. There will be N bikers. You are given initial Speed of the ith Biker by Hi and the Acceleration of ith biker as Ai KiloMeters per Hour.

The organizers want the safety of the bikers and the viewers.They monitor the Total Speed on the racing track after every Hour.
A biker whose Speed is 'L' or more, is considered a Fast Biker.
To Calculate the Total speed on the track- They Add the speed of each Fast biker ,at that Hour.

As soon as The total speed on the track is 'M' KiloMeters per Hour or more, The safety Alarm buzzes.

You need to tell what is the minimum number of Hours after which the safety alarm will buzz.

Input:

- The first Line contains T- denoting the number of test cases.
- The first line of each test case contains three space-separated integers N, M and L denoting the number of bikers and speed limit of the track respectively, and A fast Biker's Minimum Speed.
- Each of next N lines contains two space-separated integers denoting Hi and Ai respectively.

Output:

For each test case-Output a single integer denoting the minimum number of Hours after which alarm buzzes.

Constraints:

- 1<=T<=100
- 1<=N<=1e5
- 1 ≤ M,L ≤ 1e10
- 1 ≤ Hi, Ai ≤ 1e9

My code runs properly on my computer and also on the ide .But when i click submit, it crashes returning Segmentation fault(SIGSEGV).

Comment: All information, especially code, required to interpret the question and its answers should be included in the question. Links rot, rendering them useless to understanding the question, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The array `a` can contain at most 100 bikers. The problem statement specifies that the number of bikers can be up to 10,000.

Overrunning the end of the array invokes [Undefined Behaviour (UB)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which is manifesting as a segfault on the judging system. Either the UB is manifesting differently on your development system or you have not tested it with a sufficiently large number of bikers.